# Support for WFS 2.0 in QGIS 3.2.3 or geotools

Tags: qgis, openlayers, wfs, geotools

I have problem with this WFS server:

http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

I am trying to add this layer to QGIS 3.2.3 Bonn, but it does not work, I have an error. I think that the problem is with WFS 2.0.

Comment: Something to consider...  For WFS 2.0.0 the request for type is done using `typenames=&` rather than `typename` so strictly QGIS is sending an incorrect request with http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/INSPIREG2/httpauth/rest/services/INSPIRE/INSPIRE_GN/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAME=gn:NamedPlace& , however :) this service doesn't recognize typenames as a valid parameter... don't you just love standards

Answer (score 2):

Can reproduce this in QGIS 3.2.1. Errormessage:

> Layer is not valid: The layer srsname='EPSG:4326'
>   typename='prg:PRG_Granica'
>   url='http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?'
>   version='auto' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added
>   to the map. Reason:

...which is a bit meagre.

FME Desktop 2018.1 gives a more detailed message:

> Received HTTP response header: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.' from
>   'http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl:80/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAMES=prg%3APRG_Granica&NAMESPACES=xmlns%28prg%2Curn%3Agugik%3Aspecyfikacje%3Agmlas%3ApanstwowyRejestrGranic%3A1.0%29&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fgml%2Bxml%3B%20version%3D3.2'

It looks like the DescribeFeatureType link is not open to the web.

Comment: Thank you for your help. On https://www.geoportal.gov.pl/uslugi/usluga-pobierania-wfs in polish is information that this address shouldn't need log in so is strange.

Comment: The software needs the DescribeFeatureType to determine the FeatureType structure. Attributes etc.

Comment: Could you try https address? Get Capabilities works.
https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRNG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: Same problem. As long as DescribeFeatureType is blocked, software can't handle it. See http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bag/wfs?&service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=describefeaturetype for an example.

Comment: I checked your link and is wrong. You lost /exts/ This link https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType works.

Comment: I think they have a problem in their GetCapabilities document. Software is getting the link from it. Look for <ows:Operation name="DescribeFeatureType"> My guess is someone took a shortcut trying to setup a external service by duplicate & modify and didn't succeed :-)

Comment: Could you try this address? http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/INSPIREG2/httpauth/rest/services/INSPIRE/INSPIRE_GN/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?service=wfs&request=getcapabilities It seems that ulr is correct in getcapabilities.

Comment: Sure: A <schema> document was expected; however, a 'ExceptionReport' document was found - '...\FME_XSD_CACHE\fmexsd_1539689120742_6004.xml': The document under the link is: http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/INSPIREG2/httpauth/rest/services/INSPIRE/INSPIRE_GN/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType

Comment: Be aware that for WFS 2.n you/QGIS be using `typenames` not `typename`.  The error message from QGIS seems correct though, the URL cited is not valid, but it seems a problem with QGIS sending the request

Comment: Note this isn't an answer to the question, it should be an edit to the question

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150687)

Answer (score 2):

With QGIS 2.18 I got as far as this by setting version to 1.1.0:

```
Retrying request http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=prg:PRG_JednostkaPodzialuTerytorialnego&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&BBOX=47.67417567632840303,12.33569895672977346,47.67427562038612621,12.33598455538388627,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326: 3/3
2018-10-16T13:45:42 1   Server generated an exception in GetFeature response: Operation request contains an invalid parameter value. Error in filter expression: There is no (unique) geometry for FeatureType "prg:PRG_JednostkaPodzialuTerytorialnego".
2018-10-16T13:45:42 1   Download of features for layer prg:PRG_JednostkaPodzialuTerytorialnego failed or partially failed: Server generated an exception in GetFeature response: Operation request contains an invalid parameter value. Error in filter expression: There is no (unique) geometry for FeatureType "prg:PRG_JednostkaPodzialuTerytorialnego".. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5
```

Comment: http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIKINSP/httpauth/rest/services/PZGIK/PRG/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=prg:PRG_JednostkaPodzialuTerytorialnego&count=1 got me data!

Comment: Complete file (first 10.000 records) is 130 MB. Looks iso-8859-1 not UTF-8.